# How to write real-time log of log viewer to file .txt with C++?

Tags: logging, capture

I have a data log viewer application , i used C++ to display log from log viewer via adb connecting to tcp 3490 (port). The real-time log show per second.

How can i captured data log per second and write them to fix.txt? (log show 1 line, write this line to file)
IS there any way to freeze timestamp to check data?

That is hard but i hope anyone can give me suggestions.

Comment: hope any one can help